# Center columns across table row

Tags: html, .net, razor, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center my columns across the page. I'm instead stacking rows on top of each other.

**Here is my code:**

```
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    Total Open
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" id="TotalOpen">
                                    1
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    Total Unassigned
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" id="TotalUnassigned">
                                    2
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    LSA Unassigned
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" id="LSAUnassigned">
                                    3
                                </div>
                                <button id="LSAUnassignedButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">TAKE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    LS Unassigned
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" id="LSUnassigned">
                                    4
                                </div>
                                <button id="LSUnassignedButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">TAKE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    SLO Unassigned
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" id="SLOUnassigned">
                                    5
                                </div>
                                <button id="SLOUnassignedButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">TAKE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    ATTY Unassigned
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" id="ATTYUnassigned">
                                    6
                                </div>
                                <button id="ATTYUnassignedButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">TAKE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**Which looks like this:**
[stacked columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z3wl.png)

**I'd like it to look like this:**
[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuANn.png)

I'm using .cshtml and Bootstrap to try and accomplish this.
I'm not very good at HTML and I don't understand why columns are stacking vertically instead of horizontally.
I apologize for my terrible MS Paint skills.

Comment: CSS's [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) are the modern way to do generic list layout. Generelly putting `style`s in HTML is not recommended. Use classes and CSS-files instead to have a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: By the way to answer your secondary question: Your elements are aligned vertically, because you're using a `div` tag, which is a _block element_, generally causing to span the entire available width and placing the next sibling below. See [HTML Block and Inline Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) for more information on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using a `bootstrap 4`, use a **structure** row like this.
If you added a more `<div>` code will got *block element*.

**So let's try like this**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div style="font-weight:bold;">
      Total Open
    </div>
    <div id="TotalOpen">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div style="font-weight:bold;">
      Total Unassigned
    </div>
    <div id="TotalUnassigned">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div style="font-weight:bold;">
      LSA Unassigned
    </div>
    <div id="LSAUnassigned">
      3
    </div>
    <button id="LSAUnassignedButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">TAKE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```